# How did this website use the Laplace transforms?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I'm learning Laplace transforms and because my textbook is rubbish I've gone to external sources, namely this website: [Paul's Online Math Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/LaplaceTransforms.aspx). It's good for the most part, but there is an example that I really don't understand. Here it is:[image]
And here are the transforms they name:[image]

What I don't understand is how they used #32 and #5. The integral step is very confusing for me. Can someone help me to understand what it is they did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recognize that $t^{3/2}$ may be cleverly expressed as an integral of $\sqrt{t}$ and you can use the integral formula in rule 32 in conjunction with rule 5.

The integral formula says that the transform of an integral on $[0, t]$ is the transform of the integrand divided by $s$.

Comment: So is $v=t^{3\over 2}$?

Comment: No, $f(v) =\sqrt{t}$ times an appropriate constant.